# C++ : sharing fields between class and superclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, field

I am a little confused about class and superclass sharing fields. I was expecting this to be ok:

```
class SuperC {
 public:
     SuperC();
 protected:
     double value;
};

class C : public SuperC {
 public :
     C(double value);
};

SuperC::SuperC(){}
C::C(double value):SuperC(),value(value){}
```

but the compiler tells me C has no field "value". C does not inherit from the one defined in SuperC ?

many thx

Comment: Which compiler is that? g++ (gcc 4.7.2) has no complaints (called as g++ file.cpp)

Comment: mingw32-g++.exe ... I am also confused because I am pretty sure I have been doing things like the one above using my system (codeblocks on windows8) and I am surprised to see it not compiling. Something I must be missing.

Comment: Heh, my bad -- in pasting I somehow lost the constructor definitions. Silly me.

Comment: The `value(value)` code is a sure way to disaster! It's an attempt to initialize the `value` variable with itself.

Comment: @shakurov no it's not - in the initializer list, it's legal (although aesthetically ugly) - it knows `value` is the member and `(value)` the parameter.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, can you back it up by some reference? Because I had had a lot of trouble with this kind of code some time ago.

Comment: @shakurov well, can you back your claim?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, you're right, of course, thank you. I still deem this kind of code dangerous, but not critically so. And the reason is: if you change the name of the constructor's parameter in the parameter list but forget to change it in the initializer list — well, there you have it. And the code will still compile silently.

Comment: @shakurov I usually do this when the name of the variable is meaningful, for example "temperature". Then C(double temperature):temperature(temperature) might be considered ugly, but I find it more readable, especially for long constructors : C(double temperature, double pressure, double length) is clearer than C(double t, double p, double l) (I find). Is it considered as a bad habit ?

Comment: Not unless you catch yourself making a mistake like the one I've described above. Currently, for me it's not a problem at all, since the style guide I stick to demands member variable names to end with and underscore. So the code becomes `C(double temperature): temperature_(temperature)` — clear and safe.

Comment: @shakurov This underscore thing really seems to be good practice. Will do that from now on. thx !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does, but you can only initialize current class members using the constructor initialization list syntax.

You'll have to create an overloaded constructor in `SuperC` that initializes `value` and call that.

```
class SuperC {
 public:
     SuperC();
     SuperC(double v) : value(v) {}
 protected:
     double value;
};

class C : public SuperC {
 public :
     C(double value);
};

SuperC::SuperC(){}
C::C(double value):SuperC(value){}
```

Comment: My guess is that each class is responsible for initializing its own members, even in inheritance scenarios, but I'm not sure I understand why is this behavior required. Do you have any idea where this is stated in the standard?

Comment: @MihaiTodor the base class is initialized first, so talking about initializing one of its members afterwards (during SuperC's actual initialization) wouldn't make sense. IMO it's a good call, I can think of some bugs due to misstyped arguments and whatnot.

Comment: thx. I guess that will do it, but I am surprised creating a subclass of SuperC requires me to edit SuperC. After all, when creating SuperC, I did not have to assume that a subclass would ever want to initialize value during construction, and indeed I already have subclass that do not do that ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize base class members in constructor initialization list of derived class.

fix1:
 At maximum You can initialize base class(BC) constructor in derived class by passing paramerter to BC.

fix2: Assign base class members in body of derived class constructor instead of constructor initialization list

```
C::C(double value1):SuperC()
 {
      value = value1;
 }
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore sorry. Its assigning.